# How to reference resource value in main.tf from module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I'm trying to learn basics of terraform module and this is what I have
I have created resource, network and compute module in terraform, now want to pass output of vm_id to site recovery module here are the files I am using currently.

This is directory structure that I am following currently,

```
.
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
├── terraform.tfvars
└── modules
    ├── instance
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   ├── variable.tf
```

In main.tf, I create aws_vpc resource and this is an input to my instance module
The following main.tf works fine where I explicitly define values within terraform module block

```
# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

# Create a VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "dev-vpc"
  }
}

output aws_vpc_id {
  value = aws_vpc.main.id
}

module myinstance {
  source = "./modules/instance"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  instance_name = "calypso"
  ami = "ami-09c92d3eb1db3a728"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
}
```

However, when I try to move these values to "terraform.tfvars", my terrafom plan is unable to load vpc id
So the following main.tf fails to look up vpc id from the same main.tf

```
# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

# Create a VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "dev-vpc"
  }
}

output aws_vpc_id {
  value = aws_vpc.main.id
}

module "myinstance" {
  source                  = "./modules/instance"
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = var.cidr_block
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.map_public_ip_on_launch
  instance_name           = var.instance_name
  ami                     = var.ami
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
}
```

I'm not really understanding why 2nd approach wouldn't work

---Edit 1---
So here is what I'm getting when I run problematic main.tf terraform plan or apply - For some reason it is not able to retrieve vpc id that is created in the same main.tf

```
$ terraform plan
var.vpc_id       
  Enter a value:
```

This is my variables.tf

```
variable "vpc_id" {
}
variable "cidr_block" {
  type        = string
  description = "cidr block for subnet"
}

variable "map_public_ip_on_launch" {
  type        = bool
  description = "if set to true, it will map public ip on launch"
  default     = true
}

variable "instance_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of your instance"
}

variable "ami" {
  type        = string
  description = "ami for your instance"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "type of your instance"
}
```

This is my terraform.tfvars

```
cidr_block              = "10.0.0.0/24"
map_public_ip_on_launch = true
instance_name           = "calypso"
ami                     = "ami-09c92d3eb1db3a728"
instance_type           = "t3.micro"
```

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: Please update your question to include the contents of `variable.tf` and/or `variables.tf`. To be used by your `myinstance` module, the variables need to be declared somewhere that is accessible from `main.tf`.

Comment: I have updated my post with additional information to clarify